# What's the difference between the React rendering model and native toolkits

Tags: reactjs, qt, gtk

I should clarify that I'm specifically interested in the rendering model, as I understand it React rerenders only things that have changed, do native toolkits like GTK and QT not do this? What do they do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native toolkits also only re-render things that have changed, but the way that it happens is a bit different.

Native toolkit rendering consists of literally drawing pixels to the screen. In React, rendering consists of manipulating the DOM, and that is subsequently rendered by the browser into a page, and the pixels of that page are then drawn to the screen by the native toolkit that the browser is written in. So the native toolkit has a bit more freedom to optimize things at every level, whereas React only controls the DOM level.

In GTK, roughly speaking, a UI widget has the ability to "invalidate" a region of its pixels when it knows that something has changed and needs to be re-rendered. During the next paint update, the invalidated region will be redrawn according to the new state. The toolkit can combine multiple invalidations that happened in between paint updates into one, in order to optimize things, for example.